# Diffraction through 1 slit - light levels at minima points are zero or somewhat higher?

Tags: diffraction

During a few diffraction experiments, my partner and I realized that during a 2 slit experiment all minima points surely cannot be completely dark, due to the fact that the two light sources (1 from each slit) travel a different distance in the air, and therefore experience different levels of amplitude decay. The waves reach the minimum with opposite phase but not the same amplitude, and therefore don't exactly cancel each other out.

We would like to know if a similar phenomenon occurs during a 1 slit experiment, does the difference in distances travel affect the light levels at the minima?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you'll have to run an exact solution for the Huygens -Fresnell methods.  While it's true (for finite size slit) that there'll be a variation in intensity dropoff with distance, keep in mind that the "far-field" approximation assumes the distance is much greater than the slit width, which is equivalent to saying the path length from all parts of the slit is the same.